# do I need to install ndk to run opencv for android?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have an android project using opencv functions (canny algorithm and perspective transformation to be precise, implemented in java). I have sdk and ndk installed. Unfortunately I cannot remember if I needed to install ndk for this purpose or for something else. I need to write in the documentation whether I used ndk or not. Yet, I do not want to remove it to crash anything ("never change a running system"). Can anyone help?

Update: To make it more precise: Does anyone know, he/she could install and use the opencv java api without installing ndk?

Comment: you can do both probaby from [opencv's java api](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) . just don't delete the ndk, before your java code runs ;)

Answer (score 0):

When I created my last android project using openCV I wrote the openCV segment in c++ and definitely had to use the NDK to ensure the java side and C side could speak.

If you have used the Java api for openCV you might not have to, but if you have made it in c++ you do.

Hope this helps